# Facebook App Requesting a removed permission

Tags: php, facebook, permissions

I was playing with my Facebook Application's permissions to get a better understanding, so I added the permission Publish_actions (I believe that's the one I added). But then I decided to remove it from the application, so now all I request is email. However, when I use facebook to login to my site, it still requests:

```
"[appname] would like to post to your friends on your behalf"
```

In my developers.facebook.com/apps/[appid]/permissions it shows that the only permission i'm requesting is email. Where else could this permission setting be coming from?